# ASP.NET behind nginx on linux

Tags: asp.net, linux, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm currently learning ASP.NET and published my first app on my dev box.
Now I'm trying to put it behind nginx.

```
 location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @dotnet;
}
    location @dotnet {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

But this results in a 403. In Logs it says directory listing is forbidden for /path/to/wwwroot/

At the moment I'm using

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

But this way, static files are served by Kestrel.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else has this issue, here's how I solved it:

```
    root /path/to/wwwroot;
location / {
        try_files $uri @dotnet;
}
    location @dotnet {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

Replace
try_files $uri $uri/ @dotnet;
with
try_files $uri @dotnet;